# c++ Modeling a partial order concept w.r.t. custom comparators

Tags: c++, c++20

I'm modeling the concept of partial order for a custom comparator function like this:

```
template <typename F, typename T>
concept PartiallyOrderedBy = requires(F &&f, const std::remove_reference_t<T> &t1,
                                        const std::remove_reference_t<T> &t2) {
  { std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), t1, t2) } -> std::convertible_to<std::partial_ordering>;
  { std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), t2, t1) } -> std::convertible_to<std::partial_ordering>;
  // ????
  // { (t1 < t2) == (t2 > t1) };
  // { (t2 < t1) == (t1 > t2) };
  // { (t1 <= t2) == (t2 >= t1) };
  // { (t2 <= t1) == (t1 >= t2) };
};
```

`F` is basically a three-way comparator.

I want to assure the rest four requirements using concept, so I wrote this:

```
template <typename F, typename T>
concept PartiallyOrderedBy = requires(F &&f, const std::remove_reference_t<T> &t1,
                                        const std::remove_reference_t<T> &t2) {
  { std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), t1, t2) } -> std::convertible_to<std::partial_ordering>;
  { std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), t2, t1) } -> std::convertible_to<std::partial_ordering>;

  // are these really being tested???
{ bool(std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), t1, t2) == std::partial_ordering::less)
== bool(std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), t2, t1) == std::partial_ordering::greater) };
    { bool(std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), t2, t1) == std::partial_ordering::less)
== bool(std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), t1, t2) == std::partial_ordering::greater) };
    { bool(std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), t1, t2) != std::partial_ordering::less)
== bool(std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), t2, t1) != std::partial_ordering::greater) };
    { bool(std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), t2, t1) != std::partial_ordering::less)
== bool(std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), t1, t2) != std::partial_ordering::greater) };
};
```

The code runs without error ([link](https://wandbox.org/permlink/J1Q057ImUFU74Fmb)),
but I was suspicious that if these four conditions are really being tested,
so I changed them absurdly ([link](https://wandbox.org/permlink/5qdjTEu086sqkOKZ)):

```
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <compare>

template <typename F, typename T>
concept PartiallyOrderedBy = requires(F &&f, const std::remove_reference_t<T> &t1,
                                        const std::remove_reference_t<T> &t2) {
  { std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), t1, t2) } -> std::convertible_to<std::partial_ordering>;
  { std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), t2, t1) } -> std::convertible_to<std::partial_ordering>;

  // are these really being tested???
{ bool(std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), t1, t2) == std::partial_ordering::less)
== bool(std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), t2, t1) == std::partial_ordering::less) };
    { bool(std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), t2, t1) == std::partial_ordering::less)
== bool(std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), t1, t2) == std::partial_ordering::less) };
    { bool(std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), t1, t2) != std::partial_ordering::less)
== bool(std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), t2, t1) != std::partial_ordering::less) };
    { bool(std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), t2, t1) != std::partial_ordering::less)
== bool(std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), t1, t2) != std::partial_ordering::less) };
};

int main() {
    // assert passes, so they aren't being tested!!!
    static_assert(PartiallyOrderedBy<std::compare_three_way, int>);
}
```

The assert passes, so the below four requirements are doing nothing.

What is the syntactically correct way to test them?

Comment: Concepts check validity of expressions, not their truth value.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. In cppreference https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/totally_ordered#Semantic_requirements it reads that some standard library concepts are checking equality of truth values. Is it only allowed for compiler writer? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: You are misunderstanding something. The semantic requirements are not checked. It is impossible to check them. If they do not hold, the behaviour is undefined, but there (most probably) will be no compiler error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concepts (whether in C++ or any other language) always have two different kind s of requirements:

- static requirements (things that can/should be testable by the compiler)
- semantic requirements (things that need to hold but are either too expensive to practically test or simply impossible to do so)

For example, let's take a look at [[concept.strictweakorder]](https://eel.is/c++draft/concept.strictweakorder):

> ```cpp
> template<class R, class T, class U>
>  concept strict_­weak_­order = relation<R, T, U>;
> ```

This defines the syntactic requirement (you can do `r(t, u)` and `r(u, t)` and `r(t, t)` and `r(u, u)` and all of these are convertible to `bool`), but it also defines a semantic requirement:

> A relation models strict_­weak_­order only if it imposes a strict weak ordering on its arguments.

> The term strict refers to the requirement of an irreflexive relation (`!comp(x, x)` for all `x`), and the term weak to requirements that are not as strong as those for a total ordering, but stronger than those for a partial ordering. If we define `equiv(a, b)` as `!comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a)`, then the requirements are that `comp` and `equiv` both be transitive relations:
>
> - `comp(a, b) && comp(b, c)` implies `comp(a, c)`
> - `equiv(a, b) && equiv(b, c)` implies `equiv(a, c)`

You can't test this statically - this is a property that has to hold for *all* `a`, `b`, `c` in the domain of the concept. But this property *does* need to hold. If you pass in a type that is syntactically a `strict_weak_order` over `(T, T)` but isn't a semantically a `strict_weak_order` into an algorithm like `sort`, you're going to get nonsense results.  Because you violated the concept. But it's just that your violation wasn't statically detectible.

---

This idea holds exactly as well for your `PartiallyOrderedBy` concept: you have a syntactic requirement, that `f(t1, t2)` gives you a `partial_ordering`, and you have a semantic requirement , that `f` gives you a consistent ordering. But you can't check the latter - that would require checking the entire universe of values of `T`. So this part of the requirement can only be documented.

Lest you think this is some C++ limitation, we can look at the equivalent in Rust, which is called [`PartialOrd`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialOrd.html). The static requirement is simply providing a function `partial_cmp` that returns an `Option<Ordering>`, and then the semantic requirements have this long list of properties that must be met for all values in the domain. Rust can only check that `partial_cmp` has the right shape, it's up to you to provide a real ordering.

For example, a very common mistake when declaring orderings compiles just fine (even though it's possible for some `Pair`s to have both `a < b` and `b < a` to hold):

```rust
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq)]
struct Pair {
    first: i32,
    second: i32
}

impl PartialOrd for Pair {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, rhs: &Pair) -> Option<Ordering> {
        if self.first < rhs.first || self.second < rhs.first {
            Some(Ordering::Less)
        }
        else if self.first > rhs.first || self.second > rhs.first {
            Some(Ordering::Greater)
        } else {
            Some(Ordering::Equal)
        }
    }
}
```

---

Lastly, looking specifically at your implementation:

```cpp
template <typename F, typename T>
concept PartiallyOrderedBy = requires(F &&f, const std::remove_reference_t<T> &t1,
                                        const std::remove_reference_t<T> &t2) {
  { std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), t1, t2) } -> std::convertible_to<std::partial_ordering>;
  { std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), t2, t1) } -> std::convertible_to<std::partial_ordering>;
};
```

The two checks here are exactly the same - `t1` and `t2` have the same type. This can be reduced to:

```cpp
template <typename T>
using const_cref = std::remove_reference_t<T> const&;

template <typename F, typename T>
concept PartiallyOrderedBy = 
    // to pick up the semantic requirement of equality-preservation
    std::regular_invocable<F, const_cref<T>, const_cref<T>>
    // and to get the right type
    && std::convertible_to<std::invoke_result_t<F, const_cref<T>, const_cref<T>>, std::partial_ordering>;
```

When you added a requirement like this:

```cpp
{ bool(std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), t1, t2) == std::partial_ordering::less)
== bool(std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), t2, t1) == std::partial_ordering::greater) };
```

This is a requirement that *this expression* is a valid expression, nothing more. Once you require that the result of that invocation is convertible to `partial_ordering`, then (modulo dumb, pointless things)  it's going to be equality-comparable to specific `partial_ordering` values, that equality result is already `bool`, and you can of course compare two `bool`s. This adds nothing to your concept.

It's also worth commenting on the name: `PartiallyOrderedBy<F, T>`. This is backwards - in the sense that it's `F` that orders `T`, not the reverse. As is, we get:

```cpp
template <PartiallyOrderedBy<int> F>
```

A better name would be simply `PartialOrder`.